# Delphi webapplication for Azure possibilities

Tags: azure, delphi, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, delphi-11-alexandria

Is possible create Delphi webapplication deployable in Microsoft Azure cloud. I need to create webapplication which only show data from SQL database with few controls to filter data ?
Alternative solutions are welcomed. CLoud based Power BI accessible from public internet will be fine but Azure not offering this.
What I not want is coding PHP or C# because i havent skills in this.
I have skils in Delphi, Power BI, SQL Server Reporting services, Fast Report, ... then I am finding something simmilar

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at containerising your code, pushing to an Azure Container Registry and then using one of the container services to run the web application. For fast prototyping, the Azure Container Instance service can be useful because of its simplicity.

Delphi on Azure isn't a well trodden path, as a google search illustrates. Containerisation negates this and will be more useful to you when replatforming the app.

Comment: can you provide some example, how to do it ?